# avcodec_find_decoder(CODEC_ID_MPEG2TS) always NULL

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, libavformat, libav

I want to decode an incoming MPEG2-Transport Stream and then encode it to h264.
Everything works fine with the h264 Codec, but the problem is that libavcodec doesn't seem to recognize the MPEG2-Transportstream. I am basically doing it analogue to the official example:

http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/decoding__encoding_8c-source.html

```
ptrCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(CODEC_ID_MPEG2TS);
```

ptrCodec is always NULL. Could anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CODEC_ID_MPEG2TS = 0x20000, /**< _FAKE_ codec to indicate a raw MPEG-2 TS
                            * stream (only used by libavformat) */
```

`CODEC_ID_MPEG2TS` is for internal use only.

I think you are confusing codecs and file formats/containers. `libavcodec` can encode your video to h264, mpeg2video or mpeg4. If you want to put this video in avi, mpeg or mpeg-ts file you should use `libavformat`.

You should look for a different example. In this one video is encoded to h264 and then written to raw file without any containers.

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked that. In hindsight an unnecessary mistake